# Signup with Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a website using laravel and I need to integrate paypal for the registration. I have two pages where the user enter his information and the a last page where he can pay the registration fee with paypal. The customer provide me a ready button to pay throw paypal when the button is clicked it open the paypal website. It is the first time I use paypal I don't know how to finish the registration once the user pay the fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a listenner like this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/